# ssh from container to remote host without openssh-client setup

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-container

I have a scenario where Host H1 is running a docker container C1 and Host H2 (within the same network) is running a docker container C2. SSH between H1 and H2 is setup with public-key authentication. My use case is to be able to run a script on C2 by invoking a command from C1. I'm able to achieve this by setting up ssh on C1 (`openssh-client`), which involves copying the private key from H1 into the .ssh directory on C1, assigning it appropriate permissions and then running `ssh -t H2 docker exec C2 sh <script_name>`.

Is there a way to achieve this without setting up the ssh client in C1?

I tried creating the same user U in C1 as H1 that owns the private key, with the same groupID and userID and then tried ssh'ing from C1 after logging as that user, but that didn't work.

I'm not sure if copying the private key to a container image from the running host is along the best practices for dockers/vms.

Comment: Is your goal to prevent setting up the SSH client in _any_ container or just for C1?

Comment: Yes, I wish to avoid setting up the SSH client for all the containers.

Comment: Ok, this is not possible – for SSH, you need an installed SSH client somewhere. Would it be sufficient for you if you can avoid copying the private key into the container or is even installing the SSH client too much?

Comment: I'm open to installing the SSH client on a container, but want to avoid copying the private key to it, which is a necessary step I believe in setting up the ssh client. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, based on the question's comments, I'd suggest the following.

First, you definitely need some private/public key pair that the container can use, in one or the other way. Without this, SSH obviously won't work.

However, instead of copying the private key into the container, you could mount your `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable from your host machine into your container where the SSH client is installed. If your host machine is authorized to connect to your target, the container will then be, too. Minimum example:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent -e "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent" --entrypoint sh panubo/sshd -c "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no [REMOTE_MACHINE_IP]"
```

Comment: Thanks! This approach works! I'm running the container with docker-compose and had to edit my .yml file as below:

`environment:
    - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
volumes:
    - "${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}:/ssh-agent"
command: eval "ssh-agent -s/" && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`